# Why people delete complete password field if only single character is missed?

Tags: user-expectation, password, security

Including me, I have noticed it many times, people tends to delete complete password field even if they miss single character.

Anyone know why users are tend to behave in such a way? Can we do something to change this sort of user experience?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about masked password fields - correct?

Comment: Really this is not a serious question. Hello its masked how do you know where the mistake happened?

Comment: @JonH Show password option may help to check the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think because the password is masked (******* - secure text box). Since it is masked, we don't know where the mistake was, so we tend to delete the entire password and retype it.

Answer (score 0):

because some website or apps doesn't provide show password option or some users aren't used to using it.
so when we type password we try to type the password which we are already using.
human brain tends to have memorized it...when we start typing and we miss a character we tend to remove whole and type again to make sure it is perfect...

and nowadays we dont see confirm password so often..so we make sure we type it again correctly.